# How to include only certain Java classes when executing "gradle test"

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, gradle

I have JUnit test classes in both the default Java package and my specific package. My Gradle build-file contains

```
test {
    include 'edu/ucar/unidata/sruth/'
}
```

in order to exclude the JUnit test classes in the default Java package. It's not working: a `gradle test` always executes the default Java package tests as well as the package-specific tests (according to the contents of `build/reports/test`).

How do I execute only the package-specific tests?

I'm using Gradle 1.0.

ADDENDUM: Executing `gradle cleanTest` fixed the problem.

Comment: I've tried a similar example, and it works just fine for me. Only the classes in the included package are run, but not those in the default package.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, did you check the contents of `build/reports/test`?

Comment: @SteveEmmerson did you run `gradle clean` before running `gradle test`? If not, is it possible that there could be old test results in the build directory?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem. Nevertheless, the right tests get executed. `gradle cleanTest test` will get you the correct report.

Comment: @SeanReilly, I didn't run "gradle clean" or "gradle cleanTest" but the timestamps on the test results files indicated that they were new.

Answer (score 3):

I extracted following segment from Gradle official doc, hope it helps http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Some examples of using the command line option:

- gradle test --tests org.gradle.SomeTest.someSpecificFeature
- gradle test --tests *SomeTest.someSpecificFeature
- gradle test --tests *SomeSpecificTest
- gradle test --tests all.in.specific.package*
- gradle test --tests *IntegTest
- gradle test --tests *IntegTest*ui*
- gradle someTestTask --tests *UiTest someOtherTestTask --tests
  *WebTest*ui

Answer (score -13):

not sure what JUNIt is but if you have two classes with the same name you have to specify which one you are talking about like... `import java.util.Scanner;` and to use it you would declare it as `java.util.Scanner foo=new java.util.Scanner();`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this isn't a very useful answer to the question. The question is about running specific unit tests from gradle (a build system), not about accessing Java classes in another package.